# Monit's check process do not respond on process kill

Tags: ubuntu, monit

I put next file in `/etc/monit/conf.d/sidekiq`:

```
check process sidekiq with pidfile /data/my_app/current/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid
```

And expect that monit will log a message when service is not running.

I have sidekiq process running:

```
# ps aux | grep sidekiq
deploy    3265  1.1 11.9 855108 121636 ?       Sl   12:52   0:02 sidekiq 3.0.0 my_app [0 of 20 busy]
```

And have `3265` in `/data/my_app/current/tmp/pids/sidekiq.pid`

Then I restart monit (no alerts), and `kill -9 3265`.

And silence in monit's log.. Where I was wrong?

Comment: Actually, do you have others services check that works fine ?

Comment: Yes, I do the same with postgresql and it works fine. The only difference I see is how these processes are run - pg is run with `service postgresql start`, but sidekiq is run with `bundle exec sidekiq`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I check process name with `ps -p 20688 -o comm=` and realize that it named as `ruby` not `sidekiq`!

So, when I replace `check process sidekiq ...` to `check process ruby ...`, monit starts to see it and log a message when I kill this process.